# Assign different strings to char array using a variable

Tags: c, arrays, string, variables, char

The input `lakenum` is an integer from 1-5. Given that integer, the function should assign a name and return the string array to the main function, but instead I'm getting pointer errors:

> error: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   error: function returns address of local variable

I call the function using `printf ("%s", lakenamer(lakenum));`

```
int lakenamer(lakenum) {
  char lname[20] = "0";

  if (lakenum == 1) {
    strncpy(lname, "Ontario", 20);
  } else if (lakenum == 2) {
    strncpy(lname, "Erie", 20);
  } else if (lakenum == 3) {
    strncpy(lname, "Huron", 20);
  } else if (lakenum == 4) {
    strncpy(lname, "Muskoka", 20);
  } else if (lakenum == 5) {
    strncpy(lname, "Simcoe", 20);
  }

  printf("%s",lname);
  return (lname);
}
```

Comment: `strncpy` is a bad idea, you should use `strcpy` or `snprintf` instead.

Comment: @ThisGuy You should accept and upvote any of the answers if they helped you.

Comment: I cant up vote not enough credit, but I ended up just changing it so that the function would be called, and would print the data instead of returning the data back to the main function, it was easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dynamically allocate the memory for the string inside the function if you want to use it outside the function.

```
char* lakenamer( int lakenum )
{
    char* lname = ( char* )malloc( 20 );
    if ( lakenum == 1 )
    {
        strncpy( lname, "Ontario", 20 );
    }
    else if ( lakenum == 2 )
    {
        strncpy( lname, "Erie", 20 );
    }
    else if ( lakenum == 3 )
    {
        strncpy( lname, "Huron", 20 );
    }
    else if ( lakenum == 4 )
    {
        strncpy( lname, "Muskoka", 20 );
    }
    else if ( lakenum == 5 )
    {
        strncpy( lname, "Simcoe", 20 );
    }
    printf( "%s", lname );
    return ( lname );
}

int main()
{
    int lakenum = 1;
    char* s = lakenamer( lakenum );
    printf( "%s", s );

    /*
    .
    .Do other stuff with s
    .
    */

    free( s ); // Very important !!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `char *lakenamer()` and return your string (or `strdup(your_string)`) from it.

By the way, you're using `printf ("%s", lakenamer(lakenum));`, so you need the return value be `char *` but you're returning `int` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Also you are declaring lname as a local variable within your function, but returning a pointer to it to your calling function.  This isn't good, because once you return that memory address can get written over at any time.

You could instead have the caller allocate the memory, and pass its address to you, i.e.

```
char[20] lname;
lakenamer(lakenum, lname);
```

Then inside your function you can strcpy the result into lname.  Then have lakenamer return void, or int if you would like to return a success or error status code.

Comment: `char[20] lname;` --> `char lname[20];`

Answer (score -1):

error: return makes integer from pointer without a cast

**Ans:** You are getting this error because you are returning address and collecting with int without cast.

error: function returns address of local variable

**Ans:** You are getting above error because you are returning local variable address from a function which wont be exist after returning to Main() function.

Please find the below code which solves above problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void lakenamer(int, char *);

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char string[20]={0,};
    lakenamer(atoi(argv[1]), string);
    printf("\nIn Main fn:[%s]\n",string);
}

void lakenamer(int lakenum, char *str)
{
    char lname[20] = "0"; 
    //char lname[20] = {0,};

    if (lakenum == 1) {
        strncpy(lname, "Ontario", 20); //u can change lname to str
    } else if (lakenum == 2) {
        strncpy(lname, "Erie", 20);
    } else if (lakenum == 3) {
        strncpy(lname, "Huron", 20);
    } else if (lakenum == 4) {
        strncpy(lname, "Muskoka", 20);
    } else if (lakenum == 5) {
        strncpy(lname, "Simcoe", 20);
    }

    strcpy(str, lname);
    printf("%s",lname);
    //return (lname);//do not return any reference for local variable
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing instead if just giving a code sample